# Lightswitch 2012 Deployment security database

Tags: security, roles, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am fairly new to Lightswitch (2012) and am confused on how the membership tables are deployed if using Windows Authentication with roles specified. My confusion lies in the two connection strings, one has a key called _intrinsic and the other has a guid of sorts as the key. 
When I deploy my application as a OOB I get a connection issue and the app fails. If I deploy with no security then the app works fine. I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong within the deployment settings as I have three spots to enter conn string values. Can anyone please help with this and give me a high level as to which connections are used for application data and which ones are used for security?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add users/roles to your application, then these are stored in what's called the *intrinsic* database. The two connection strings are for:

1. An *administrator* account, which has the required permissions in the target SQL Server instance to ***create*** the intrinsic database.
2. A *user* account, which has the required permissions in the target SQL Server instance that allows the LS application to ***connect*** to the deployed database (this also includes access to any tables/entities that you create in LightSwitch).

LS V1 (2011) used to have the *administrative* connection string appear in the Publish Wizard **above** the *user* connection string, but from memory, the order has been switched around in LS V2 (2102). But thye're clearly labelled, so there shouldn't be any confusion as to which is which, now that you know what they're used for.

The only other connection strings you might see in the wizard (or in the web.config file) is for any **attached** data sources. These database will already exist, so there's no need for an administrative connection string, so there's just the one connection string, for user connections to it.

Comment: I have all of the role based tables / procs created but keep on getting an "unable to authenticate. Access is denied" Error.

Comment: See if this forum post helps: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/lightswitchgeneral/thread/5af7cdcc-e938-47d8-9fd3-65f155ca27f5